# Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts", which threw an exception:

Tags: react-native

I'm working in react native on my app and I keep getting this error:

> Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts", which threw an exception: Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library, make sure you followed installation steps here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/
> Make sure reanimated's babel plugin is installed in your babel.config.js (you should have 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' listed there - also see the above link for details)
> Make sure you reset build cache after updating the config, run: yarn start --reset-cache
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
> A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an
> early initialization error when loading React Native.
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
> A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an
> early initialization error when loading React Native.

I'm not sure what the error is so I haven't tried anything yet. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you done all the steps of `react-native-reanimated` installation process mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to `babel.config.js` as follows.

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
        plugins: [
            'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
        ],
    };
};
```

And run following commands in the terminal and this works fine me.

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

`expo start -c`